astro.js - using wasm straight in the svelte island
I am using astro framework with svelte as interactive island.
and I want to use wasm inside my svelte island directly to process some [markdown][1]. but it is not so straight forward that I can just import the files.
After some reading online, someone suggest that can try put every related files (markdown.es.js, markdown.es.js.map, markdown.wasm) into /public and link them straight. I tried that then import:
  import * as markdown from "/wasm/markdown.es.js"

then got error below:

[ERROR] [vite] Internal server error: Cannot import non-asset file
/wasm/markdown.es.js which is inside /public. JS/CSS files inside
/public are copied as-is on build and can only be referenced via
 or  in html. If you want to get the URL of
that file, use /wasm/markdown.es.js?url instead.

My hunch is I still need to do some config at either vite or svelte or astro side. But I am totally not sure how to start.
How can I resolve this?

the important part is "which is inside /public". You should place all files that need to transformed in /src
